# Plotting sort of a heatmap whose colors are a result of a function x,y -> r,g,b

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary which maps XY tuples to RGB tuples. For example,

```
d = {
    (0, 0): (0, 0, 0),
    (0, 1): (0, 0, 200),
    }
```

I wish to plot some sort of heatmap, which, at a given XY coordinate, will have color which is the average of the colors in the dict, weighted by their reciprocal distances; as if they were "sources of light" or so.

In the given example, the coordinate `(0, 0.5)` should be colored with `(0, 0, 100)` and the coordinate `(0, 0.1)` should be colored with `(0, 0, 20)`.

My question is rather technical: how do I let `pyplot` plot a pixel image with colors retrieved from a function `f(x, y) -> (r, g, b)`?

Comment: Is there an issue with creating the arrays first just using vectorized Numpy and passing the result to `imshow`? This seems much more straightforward than hacking `imshow` to take a function and a dict. In theory it would require (roughly) the same number of operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your X-Y grid:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

width, height = 300, 500

xs = numpy.arange(width)
ys = numpy.arange(height)
data = numpy.dstack(numpy.meshgrid(xs, ys))
```

You should just map these to `(r, g, b)` tuples. The following is pretty slow, but how to speed it up depends on what your function does.

```
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb

import random
def data_to_color(x, y):
    return (
        (x/width)**(0.5+random.random()*2),
        (y/height)**3,
        (x/width*y/height)*0.6 + random.random()*0.4
    )

colors = [[data_to_color(x, y) for x, y in row] for row in data]
colors = numpy.array(colors)
colors.shape
#>>> (500, 300, 3)
```

Then `imshow` can give the wanted output:

```
plt.imshow(colors, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.show() result]

Now, if you want to interpolate from your points as you say, you can use `scipy.interpolate`. I'll make a dictionary to extrapolate from the function above:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

gridpoints = data.reshape(width*height, 2)
d = {(x, y): data_to_color(x, y) for x, y in gridpoints if not random.randint(0, 1000)}

len(d)
#>>> 142
```

Extract the dictionary into `numpy` arrays, and separate the colours (it might be possible to avoid the separation, but you can test that yourself):

```
points, values = zip(*d.items())

points = numpy.array(points)
values = numpy.array(values)

reds   = values[:, 0]
greens = values[:, 1]
blues  = values[:, 2]
```

Then run `griddata` on the points:

```
new_reds   = griddata(points, reds,   (data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1]), method='linear')
new_greens = griddata(points, greens, (data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1]), method='linear')
new_blues  = griddata(points, blues,  (data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1]), method='linear')

new_colors = numpy.dstack([new_reds, new_greens, new_blues])
new_colors[numpy.isnan(new_colors)] = 0.5
```

And plot:

```
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'k-', linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)

plt.imshow(new_colors, extent=(0, width, 0, height), origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.show() interpolated output]

And, finally, if you want *extrapolation* too, I copied some code [from here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85503/smoothing-results-from-scipy-griddata-interpolatioin):

```
import scipy

def extrapolate_nans(x, y, v):
    '''  
    Extrapolate the NaNs or masked values in a grid INPLACE using nearest
    value.

    .. warning:: Replaces the NaN or masked values of the original array!

    Parameters:

    * x, y : 1D arrays
        Arrays with the x and y coordinates of the data points.
    * v : 1D array
        Array with the scalar value assigned to the data points.

    Returns:

    * v : 1D array
        The array with NaNs or masked values extrapolated.
    '''

    if numpy.ma.is_masked(v):
        nans = v.mask
    else:
        nans = numpy.isnan(v)
    notnans = numpy.logical_not(nans)
    v[nans] = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x[notnans], y[notnans]), v[notnans],
        (x[nans], y[nans]), method='nearest').ravel()
    return v

new_reds   = extrapolate_nans(data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1], new_reds)
new_greens = extrapolate_nans(data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1], new_greens)
new_blues  = extrapolate_nans(data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1], new_blues)

new_colors = numpy.dstack([new_reds, new_greens, new_blues])

plt.imshow(new_colors, extent=(0, width, 0, height), origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

[image: ply.show() extrapolated interpolated output]

---

**EDIT:** Maybe something more like

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

width, height = 300, 500

xs, ys = numpy.mgrid[:width, :height]
coordinates = numpy.dstack([xs, ys])

light_sources = {
    (0, 0): (0, 0, 0),
    (300, 0): (0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0): (0, 0, 0),
    (300, 500): (0, 0, 0),
    (100, 0): (0, 0, 200),
    (200, 150): (100, 70, 0),
    (220, 400): (255, 255, 255),
    (80, 220): (255, 0, 0),
}

weights = numpy.zeros([width, height])
values = numpy.zeros([width, height, 3])
```

For each light source:

```
for coordinate, value in light_sources.items():
```

Compute the (inverse) distances. Use `+1e9` to prevent infinities, although this will have silly failures so a more rigorous fix would be important later:

```
    shifted_coordinates = coordinates - coordinate + 1e-9
    inverse_distances = (shifted_coordinates ** 2).sum(axis=-1) ** (-1/2)
```

Add it to the sum and the sum weighting:

```
    weights += inverse_distances
    values  += inverse_distances[:, :, numpy.newaxis].repeat(3, axis=-1) * value / 255
```

Divide by the weighting to have the average:

```
values /= weights[..., numpy.newaxis]
```

And show...

```
plt.imshow(values, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

For this:

[image: plt.show() for light-source variant]

The reason I didn't go for this originally is because the value at `(0, 0.1)` in your example is not `(0, 0, 20)` but:

```
distances = [0.9, 0.1]
inverse_distances = [10/9, 10]
sum_weighting = 100 / 9
blue_levels = 200 / (109/90) = 18
```

so it should be `(0, 0, 18)` by this definition.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it doesn't deal with the difficult part of the question, which is how to perform weighted RGB colour mixing based on the distance from an arbitrary number of "light" sources.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's part of the question or just the preface. I'll think about it, though.

Comment: Well, I gave it a shot.

Comment: More than a shot. I'm still not sure it addresses the original point, but it is legitimately awesome. If I could +1 again, I would.

Comment: This is awesome, I don't know how I've missed that so long.